# How to write jest test cases for navigation using jest library

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, jestjs, enzyme

I am new to Jest test cases writing, Trying to write the test case for checking navigation in an react application.

Currently I have written test case which works like below: I have Login page which is having register link on it, which redirects user to the Register page. So what I am checking is 1. Loading the login page 2. Triggered Register link click event 3. So user moved to the Register page

but I am not able to check if the Register page is loaded or not? Is there any way to check the snapshot of the "Register" page and link in URL.

I have used **jest**, **enzyme** and **react-test-render** as shown in below code.

**Login Page Html --**

```
<React.Fragment>       
<BodyContainer noDrawer fullSpan>
  <Grid container spacing={0} className={classes.gridContainer}>
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={7} className="login--form">
      <div className="login--form--container">
        <img src={LogoPurple} alt="ABL" className="onboarding-logo" />
        <h3>Welcome back! Please login to your account.</h3>
          {error ? <p>{error}</p> : null}
          <Field name="email" component={renderTextField} label="Email" style={styles.formField}/>
          <Field name="password" component={renderTextField} label="Password" style={styles.formField} />
          <Field name="rememberMe" component={renderCheckbox} label="Remember Me" />
          <div className="has-spacing">
            <Button variant="raised" size="large" color="primary" className="extraLarge" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
              Login
            </Button>
          </div>

          <Link to="forgot-password">Forgot Password</Link>
            <p className="need-account">
              Need an account?
              <Link to="/register">
                <strong> Sign up</strong>
            </p>
          </Link>
        <LegalLinks />
      </div>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</BodyContainer>
```

**test case --**

```
 it('Terms of use link test ',()=>{
const component = renderer.create(
  <StaticRouter location="terms" context={props}>
    <Link to="/terms">Terms of use.&nbsp;</Link>
</StaticRouter>);
let tree = component.toJSON();
expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot(); });

it('Privacy policy link test ',()=>{
const component = renderer.create(
  <StaticRouter location="privacy" context={props}>
    <Link to="/privacy">Privacy policy</Link>
</StaticRouter>);
let tree = component.toJSON();
expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();});
```

**In above code register is the link used to navigate.
please give me any suggestion. 
Thanks....**

Comment: You can go about just checking the `location` from state. This would indicate that you've moved to the new route.  Using shallow rendering, I think this is the best option.

Comment: Ok, Thanks.
 Let me try.

Comment: How is this question related to How to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49728333/how-to-write-jest-test-cases-for-navigation-in-react?